# How to rename a perlbrew installed version

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I installed Perl 5.32 with the name `perl-5.32.0`

```
$ perlbrew list
* perl-5.32.0
```

The installation was updated with `perlbrew upgrade-perl` and I now have 5.32.1

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

How can I rename the installed version to 5.32 (without the minor version number which is now wrong)?